# Laravel queue: How to track progress and know which sub jobs suceeded/failed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, queue, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

Currently im building a platform where android FCM messages have to be sent out to devices which has my app installed.

I have a notification builder in my backend which will allow an admin to add notifications. This also dispatches a NotificationJob which will query the DB and find all devices which has installed the app (say 1000 end users) and dispatches a sub job each to send the push notification out (1000 subjobs).

In the notification admin panel I want to display a status like 950 succeeded/50 failed corresponding to each notification entry.

Is something like this possible with laravel queues?

Also are subjobs really a overkill for this?

Comment: Does your queued job get a response from the (G?)FCM API? I'm unsure how you're sending those notifications (is it using the laravel notification system?)

Comment: Yes its uses the laravel notification system. Maybe I should not have mentioned FCM if its a complex topic. I just want a generic solution that can be implemented in any kind of job. Thanks